# Rewriting multiple rules in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i'm not an expert in mod rewriting. i'm trying to rewrite multiple rules in .htaccess  of my root directory which are as following:

```
RewriteEngine On

#HEADER REDIRECTION
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\..+$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
#FINISH HEADER REDIRECTION

#PREVENT IF NOT USER_AGENT
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^$
RewriteRule .* - [F]
#FINISH PREVENT IF NOT USER_AGENT

#PREVENT UNEXPECTED USER_AGENT STRING
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Custo [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^FlashGet [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^GetRight  [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^BlackWidow [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^aHMView 
RewriteRule .* - [F]
#FINISH PREVENT UNEXPECTED USER_AGENT STRING

#BYPASS STRANGERS
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER}&nbsp;!^http://www.site.com [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F]
#FINISH PYPASS STRANGERS
```

but the rules are causing internal server error 500

is there any mistake in it? if yes, how should i write it properly?

thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Try the "Basic .htaccess code syntax checker and validator" http://www.lyxx.com/freestuff/002.html or ".htaccess validator v1.06" http://shop.alterlinks.com/htaccess-validator/htaccess-validator.php

Answer (score 1):

Your rules are fin. They work for me in a blank htaccess file on a vanilla Apache 2.2 server. You probably don't have mod_rewrite loaded. Check that in your httpd.conf, the line that looks something like:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

isn't commented out.

Comment: on my Apache 2.0 Handler (version:20051115) `mod_alias` `mod_rewrite` `mod_so` etc. are enabled. i already can rewrite other rules there. the above rules together aren't working on my server. by the way, any idea why  
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST` returns error by `.htaccess` syntax checker? thanks,